# Clang Error: Linker command when integrating AdColony sdk in iPhone app

Tags: ios, sdk, path, linker-errors, ads

ers,

I'm having trouble integrating AdColony's Video Ad system into my iPhone app. I feel like I've followed the documentation to a T so far, but I cant even get passed the first check point.

Documentation Download link Here:
https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/tree/master/Documentation

Here's the error I'm getting:

ld: file not found: PATH/TO/LIBRARY/libAdColony.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help or insight is very much appreciated !
Thanks for listening everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, it looks like you're using an optional step (using the `-force_load` compiler setting). When you do this, you need to specify the actual path (from your project's root directory) to the `libAdColony.a` file; the `PATH/TO/LIBRARY/` bit is a placeholder you should replace. If it's not necessary for you to use the `-force_load` flag for your project to work correctly, I'd recommend removing it. Also, for a faster response, don't hesitate to get in touch with us at our support email address, which is listed in the documentation.